# how to add a scroll bar to react project?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm working on a website with react.js framework but the scroll bar not appear in normal website the scroll bar appear automatically but in react.js is not, how can do it ??

the problem is in Css html o react components or what?

Comment: What code are you using?

Comment: Do you use overflow: hidden somewhere? That would be my first guess, without having any code to look at.

Comment: yes it is thank you !!

Comment: There is nothing we can reproduce here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why people says it is not useful question
this little thing can make people crazy.

check if you have the following line somewhere in your `css` file
`overflow: hidden`,

Note: If you want to make the `div` scrollable for mobile devices, make sure you haven't styled this div with
`position: fixed`.